# Scalable training/updating of many small LSTM models

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, scalability, parallel

My situation is that I have many thousands of devices which each have their own specific LSTM model for anomaly prediction. These devices behave wildly differently so I don't think there is any way to have a shared global model, unfortunately. Periodically I will update each device model with the new data from the device - so maybe once per day I will load an additional daily batch of readings and use the properties of stateful LSTM training to update the model.

Each of these models is very small, containing at most 10-20 thousand readings in their whole history, and fitting into memory on even a modest GPU. Training from scratch is relatively quick, and updating a single batch should be even more so, as typically there are only 48 new readings/day (30 minute intervals), but going as high as 1440 readings/day.

My question is - **what is an optimal architecture for handling all of these models and updates?** They are all independent and small, so I don't see a need for anything distributed, but there are so many of them that I am unsure how to proceed. I am thinking that perhaps using something like an AWS 'large' GPU cluster, with each GPU loading a serialized model from the DB, updating with a new batch of data, and writing back could work - however, I suspect that having to repeatedly compile the models will be a blocker and that being able to do only 4 at a time is woefully insufficient.

Alternatively, it may be possible to do the 'initial' training on some kind of powerful GPU rig, and then do the batch updates on CPU's, which would make it easier to run many instances in parallel. Is this an example of where Spark might be useful?

Any advice is appreciated - including 'your premise is absurd, why would you do this!' This is only one of many ways available to do the anomaly detection, so if the architecture implementation is unfeasible, I will abandon the LSTM's altogether and try something simpler.

Comment: Spark may or may not be helpful, it's a fine DB, but I don't see a specific resource constraint mentioned in your question that directly relates to something Spark does better (or worse) than other DB's, so I'm not sure how it fits in. It sounds like you need to do a lot of computationally non-intensive operations constantly or in parallel. Incremental training is of course a good idea. It sounds like the GPU is not a limiting factor. If the bottleneck is all of the reading and writing then perhaps what you should focus on is fast I/O via SSD and enough cores for sufficient parallelization.

Comment: @Hack-R isn't a DB, it is a processing engine. Now to comment on the question, considering the size of your data, using Spark is an overkill. To be clear, training thousands of models won't be done in parallel but sequentially in Spark. Parallelization will be executed on for each model training nevertheless. Also considering the size of your data, you can perfectly train each model in a local manner.

Comment: @eliasah That's just a matter of semantics. I've used Spark daily for 2 years and everyone I know refers to it as such. Including the Spark Summit, e.g.  "Not Your Father's Database: How to Use Apache Spark Properly in Your Big Data Architecture" and Google, e.g. "Spark Database - Tools for Modern Applications‎".

Comment: It's not. I use spark also daily but semantic how you call it is not the subject here nevertheless. It's not a DB.

Comment: @eliasah I disagree entirely. But you should contact the Spark Summit and Google to let them know how wrong they are.

Comment: That makes us even. I'm not looking for a confirmation from you to decide whether it is a DB or not. Now please if you don't have anything to add to the question, don't waste my time ! Have a nice day.